# Laravel validation pdf mime

Tags: validation, laravel, mime

I have tried below mime types for validating PDF files.but none of them doesnt pass the validation .

```
  $rules  = [
     ....
    "file" => "required|mimes:application/pdf, application/x-pdf,application/acrobat, applications/vnd.pdf, text/pdf, text/x-pdf|max:10000"
     ....
       ]
```

Comment: Does your form accept files? Like did you use something as: `'files' => true` when opening a form?

Comment: I believe the rule you are looking for when validating `application/pdf` is `mimetypes`, not `mimes`. Note that @Froxz response works when you are validating `pdf` agains `mimes` https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: Hi @Jon, thank you for your comment, keep in mind when question was asked only `Laravel 5.1` was available and this rule was added in 5.2, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi @Froxz - all good, though Laravel 5.2 was released in December 2015 (2 months prior to the question being asked). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel#Release_history

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just add file extension

```
$rules  = [
    "file" => "required|mimes:pdf|max:10000"
]
```

From laravel Docs:

> Even though you only need to specify the extensions, this rule
>   actually validates against the MIME type of the file by reading the
>   file's contents and guessing its [MIME type](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#rule-mimes).

---

**Update:**

Starting from **Laravel 5.2**, you could validate file upload against full MIME type, [new validation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-mimetypes) rule called: `mimetypes`.

```php
$rules  = [
    "file" => "required|mimetypes:application/pdf|max:10000"
]
```

Comment: In laravel `8.x` I solved my problem with PDF using: `mimes:pdf,doc,docx`.